# Which AWS Cloudwatch alarm metric to choose for specific number of website hits within a minute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I am trying to set a Cloudwatch alarm for my Application Load Balancer. Requirement is that,

> If my website reaches a number of 10 in a minute, my ELB has to add another instance to reduce the load
>
> Similarly, if my website has 5 or less number of hits, my instance count will go down one at a time.

I have `Disk reads`, `Disk Read Operations` and `Network In` options to be selected. I am not sure which one has to be chosen among these.

Comment: Can I ask why only these metrics? ALB has many other more useful metrics, e.g. `ActiveConnectionCount` or `RequestCountPerTarget`.

Comment: Hi Mercin, Since I want to scale down as well, I am using `Scale the Auto Scaling group using step or simple scaling policies` option instead of `Scale the Auto Scaling group using a target tracking scaling policy` option

Comment: A single target tracking policy will handle scale up and scale down.  But even if your using a stimple or step scaling policy, the metrics you listed are typically not good ones to scale on since they aren't proportional to the load on the ASG.  Usually using CPU usage or RequestCountPerTarget are good for most applications